# How to toggle a div from one button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can carry this task by using `.toggle()` in version 1.8 of jquery 
but am using /jquery/3.2.1/ on my site and the `.toggle()` is not working properly

in one of my page am using this in my first section

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideBtn").click( function(){
    $(".slide-div").animate({left : '0'},"slow");
    $(".slide-div").css({"top": "0","z-index": "9"});
    $("p").animate({fontSize: '100px'},2000);
    $("#slideBtn").fadeOut("slow");
    });
$(".closedBtn").click( function(){
    $(".slide-div").animate({left:'-820px'},"slow");
    $(".slide-div").css({"top": "0","z-index": "9"});
    $("p").animate({fontSize: '14px'}, "slow");
    $("#slideBtn").fadeIn("slow");

    });


    });
```

it works fine but when i have to do the same task by clicking on the same button as it is in my bottom section by clicking it first time it works fine but if i click multiple time it wont work fine so i have issues with this code i need help with this code thank's

**Here is the code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(".new-box").animate({left : '0'},"slow");
    });
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var left = $(".new-box").css('left');
        if(left == '-820'){
            $(".new-box").animate({left : '0'},"slow" );
            }
            else {$("#button").on("click",function(){ $(".new-box").animate({left : '-820px'},"slow");});}

    });


    });
```

**Here is the example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slideBtn").click(function() {
    $(".slide-div").animate({
      left: '0'
    }, "slow");
    $(".slide-div").css({
      "top": "0",
      "z-index": "9"
    });
    $("p").animate({
      fontSize: '100px'
    }, 2000);
    $("#slideBtn").fadeOut("slow");
  });
  $(".closedBtn").click(function() {
    $(".slide-div").animate({
      left: '-820px'
    }, "slow");
    $(".slide-div").css({
      "top": "0",
      "z-index": "9"
    });
    $("p").animate({
      fontSize: '14px'
    }, "slow");
    $("#slideBtn").fadeIn("slow");

  });


});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".new-box").animate({
      left: '0'
    }, "slow");
  });
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var left = $(".new-box").css('left');
    if (left == '-820') {
      $(".new-box").animate({
        left: '0'
      }, "slow");
    } else {
      $("#button").on("click", function() {
        $(".new-box").animate({
          left: '-820px'
        }, "slow");
      });
    }

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="float:left;width:1020px;">
  <div class="main" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: #f5f5f5;position:relative;">
    <button id="slideBtn">Play</button>
    <div class="slide-div" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: aqua;position:absolute;left:-820px;"><button class="closedBtn" style="float:right;border:1px solid green;border-radius:50%;padding:10px;position:relative;top:0;right:0; ">X</button>
      <p style="width:100%;">Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="showdiv" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: red;position:relative;">
    <button id="button">shw</button>
    <div class="new-box" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: #f98463;position:absolute;left:-820px;"><button class="closedBtn" style="float:right;border:1px solid green;border-radius:50%;padding:10px;position:relative;top:0;right:0; "></div>
</div>


</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tx4p3sbh/)**

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: **Notice:** no need to use `$(document).ready(function() {` twice.

Comment: if you open the snippet or fiddle you can see the bottom button works fine first time but when you click it again and again it wont work the way it works the first time

Comment: *"I can carry this task by using .toggle() in version 1.8 of jquery but am using /jquery/3.2.1/ on my site and the .toggle() is not working properly"* There is no call to `toggle` in your code.

Comment: What do you mean of `with the what now?` @freedomn-m

Comment: @Mr.x I know that i can use ~$(document).ready(function()~ it one time but i was asking the query first time thats why my silly mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used a debugger on the code, you'd see that `left` comes back from `css` with a units value on it (e.g., `-810px`, not `-810`). You're also hooking up a `click` handler *within* a `click` handler, which is almost never a good idea.

I wouldn't rely on the return value from `css` at all; instead, I'd use a flag class (and probably do the animation with CSS, but that's out of scope):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".new-box").animate({
      left: '0'
    }, "slow");
  });
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var left = $(".new-box").css('left');
    if ($(".new-box").hasClass('on-left')) {
      $(".new-box").removeClass('on-left').animate({
        left: '0'
      }, "slow");
    } else {
      $(".new-box").addClass('on-left').animate({
        left: '-820px'
      }, "slow");
    }
  });
});
```

There I've added a class initially to the element, and then I use it as a flag for what to do when the click occurs.

Live copy:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#slideBtn").click(function() {
    $(".slide-div").animate({
      left: '0'
    }, "slow");
    $(".slide-div").css({
      "top": "0",
      "z-index": "9"
    });
    $("p").animate({
      fontSize: '100px'
    }, 2000);
    $("#slideBtn").fadeOut("slow");
  });
  $(".closedBtn").click(function() {
    $(".slide-div").animate({
      left: '-820px'
    }, "slow");
    $(".slide-div").css({
      "top": "0",
      "z-index": "9"
    });
    $("p").animate({
      fontSize: '14px'
    }, "slow");
    $("#slideBtn").fadeIn("slow");

  });


});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $(".new-box").animate({
      left: '0'
    }, "slow");
  });
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var left = $(".new-box").css('left');
    if ($(".new-box").hasClass('on-left')) {
      $(".new-box").removeClass('on-left').animate({
        left: '0'
      }, "slow");
    } else {
      $(".new-box").addClass('on-left').animate({
        left: '-820px'
      }, "slow");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="float:left;width:1020px;">
  <div class="main" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: #f5f5f5;position:relative;">
    <button id="slideBtn">Play</button>
    <div class="slide-div" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: aqua;position:absolute;left:-820px;"><button class="closedBtn" style="float:right;border:1px solid green;border-radius:50%;padding:10px;position:relative;top:0;right:0; ">X</button>
      <p style="width:100%;">Hello</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="showdiv" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: red;position:relative;">
    <button id="button">shw</button>
    <div class="new-box on-left" style="width:800px;height: 500px;background-color: #f98463;position:absolute;left:-820px;"><button class="closedBtn" style="float:right;border:1px solid green;border-radius:50%;padding:10px;position:relative;top:0;right:0; "></div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: *Still second button action not works correctly.* Try to close.

Comment: @Mr.x: I did. It does. ...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Toggling works fine but when you want to close second  `animaton`, it does not work.

Comment: @Mr.x: Sorry, I'm still not following you. If I click the "shw" button, it slides right and shows. If I click the "shw" button again, it slides left and doesn't show. OP also seems to think it's working. (I haven't looked at **other** parts of it, if there's something else unrelated that isn't working.)

Comment: Yes what you mentioned works fine but when you click on `shw` then if you want to close via "Close" (OR that empty circle) in the right side it won't close it. But if it's not part of OP's question, forget it.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$("selector").click(..` twice like you have, you're assigning two click handlers - so both run at the same time (both run on a single click).

You need to check the state within the click button, eg:

```
var isshown = false;
```

```js
var isshown = true;
$("#btn").click(function() {
    if (isshown) {
       // do your animates here, simple hide/show as example
       $("#content").hide();
    } else {
       $("#content").show();
    } 
    isshown = !isshown;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='content'>content</div>
<button id='btn'>click</button>
```

There are many ways to check this, above is an example.